# String.MemberwiseClone() method called through reflection doesn't work, why?

Tags: c#, reflection, shallow-clone

Let me start by saying that I know it is a protected method and I'm not supposed to call it, but shouldn't it work since **MemberwiseClone** is defined in the **Object** class and **String** inherits from it?

So this is the cloning method (I removed null reference handling to focus on what's important):

```
public static T ShallowClone<T>(T obj)
{
    MethodInfo memberwiseClone;
    memberwiseClone = obj.GetType().GetMethod("MemberwiseClone", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
    return (T)memberwiseClone.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

And if I call it like this:

```
string str = ShallowClone("My string");
```

The resulting string (str) will be:

```
"M\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Wild guess: the underlying native is a pointer, `MemberwiseClone` takes the value (i.e. the first character) and the length without copying the rest of it.

Comment: What is the point of cloning a string?

Comment: I was cloning elements from a collection and happened to find a string along the way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling it and it is working. The problem is that `String.MemberwiseClone` is not doing what you are expecting it to do. It appears to create a string with the same length as the original string, but only copies over the first character.

I think the lesson to be learned here is: When you call a method you're not supposed to call, be very careful, learn what it does, and don't assume too much.