# Assigning list with one value after index

Tags: c#, list

is it possible to block set a list with a value after a particular index, fast?

How is the below logic can be written in C#?. I could use a different collection if I can do the same.

```
List<int> mylist = new List<int>(10);

int index = 3;
int value = 11;
mylist.SetValuesafterIndex(index, value);
```

EDIT:

Clarification: I mean, I want indices 3 to 9 inclusive to be set to value 11

Comment: @DavidHeffernan-yes, absolutely

Comment: Changed the question. I still think the first line was quiet specific about what I want.

Comment: @Jimmy Well, I understood, but I think there was some scope for misunderstanding. Anyway, it is quite clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you want is not provided by `List<T>`. So, whilst it is something of a statement of the obvious, you could perfectly well write:

```
for (int i = index; i < list.Count; i++) 
    list[i] = value;
```

The only other option that springs to mind is to use `RemoveRange` to remove all items from `Index` to the end, and then call `AddRange` to add your new values.

Since you state performance as being an issue, you should carry out some measurements of the options with your real-world usage scenarios.

Comment: I tend to agree. RemoveRange and AddRange looks like the only option. Will wait for some more time for any magical ideas :-).

Comment: I suspect that there will be scenarios where the `for` loop is faster, and other scenarios where the alternative is faster.

Comment: I see what you mean. msdn says addrange and removerange are o(n) operations. I was under a different impression after reading this answer where Jon suggest to use addrange for list initialization http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466946/how-to-initialize-a-listt-to-a-given-size-as-opposed-to-capacity

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
mylist[index] = value;
```

It's unclear if you want it to be at `index` or `index + 1`.  Just adjust the above as appropriate

Comment: I want  a "block" set after the index for the size of list.

Comment: @Jimmy what is a block set?

Comment: Set all the items in the list after an index to a given value. For example, if the size of the list is 10, I want to set all values after index 3 (indices 3-9) to a given value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a generic method like this:

```
 static void SetRangeValues<T>(List<T> list,int start,int end,T value)
 {
       if(end > list.Count() || start < 0) 
           throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();

        for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
        {
            list[i] = value;
        }
 }
```

And you can use it like this:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(0,10));

Console.WriteLine("Before: ");
list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

SetRangeValues(ref list, 3, 10, 2000);

Console.WriteLine("After: ");
list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

// Output:

Before:
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
After:
0
1
2
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
2000
```

If you want to set values until the end of the List, simply you can pass `list.Count` as `end` parameter:

```
SetRangeValues(list, 3, list.Count(), 2000);
```

Comment: It's a little pointless testing for and throwing `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` given that `List<T>` already does so. You may as well let it do the work and so perform one fewer check.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you right,but maybe OP wants to change that behavior,maybe he want to display a message and return from the function immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure about performance, but an one line answer could be:

```
myList.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat(0, index).Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(value, 10 - index)));
```

Comment: But, the values in the list before index cannot be discarded.

Comment: It's a list of int, the value before index must be initialize before processing further.