# How can I get a Span<T> from a List<T> while avoiding needless copies?

Tags: c#, memory

I have a `List<T>` containing some data. I would like to pass it to a function which accepts `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

```
List<T> items = GetListOfItems();
// ...
void Consume<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> buffer)
// ...
Consume(items??);
```

In this particular instance T is `byte` but it doesn't really matter.

I know I can use `.ToArray()` on the List, and the construct a span, e.g.

```
Consume(new ReadOnlySpan<T>(items.ToArray()));
```

However this creates a (seemingly) unneccessary copy of the items. Is there any way to get a Span directly from a List? `List<T>` is implemented in terms of `T[]` behind the scenes, so in theory it's possible, but not as far as I can see in practice?

Comment: I don't think you can until they implement this for `List<T>`, in natural ways. Otherwise you can use reflection to access backing array and call `AsSpan` on it.

Comment: If you're wanting to use `Span<T>` for performance reasons, perhaps you shouldn't be starting with a `List<T>` in the first place?

Comment: The internal buffer could be reallocated by the next `Add` operation which means the `Span` will end up pointing to a dangling array and stale data. Imagine adding 2 items to an empty list, taking a span, then adding another item, causing a reallocation and then *modifying* all stored items. The span will end up looking at a stale copy of the data

Comment: I have deleted my reflection answer because i agree that it's not a good idea to use the internal array of the list. There are some issues with it: 1)if the list gets modified afterwards the array will be reallocated and the `ReadOnlySpan` holds a dangled array reference. 2) The internal array gets a size that will be doubled whenever it needs to be increased, so it might contain default values for that type which aren't contained in the list(`array.Length > list.Count`). If you are going to truncate that part you have to create a new array anyway.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for the explanation. If you write that up as an answer I'll accept it for the question

Comment: @DavidG That's a bit silly. `List<T>` is fast. Just because it abstracts away the need to manually recreate the underlying array at a larger size yourself doesn't automatically make it slow. It's still just an array underneath.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In .Net 5.0, you can use [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-5.0) ([source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/CollectionsMarshal.cs,b48f5c98e43560f8), [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27061)) to get the underlying array of a `List<T>` as a `Span<T>`.

Keep in mind that this is still unsafe: if the `List<T>` reallocates the array, the `Span<T>` previously returned by `CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan` won't reflect any further changes to the `List<T>`. (Which is why the method is hidden in the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.CollectionsMarshal` class.)

Comment: Does this returned Span include yet-unused List array slots?

Comment: @Vinigas It does not.

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for all the comments explaining that there's no actual way to do it and how exposing the internal Array inside List could lead to bad behaviour and a broken span.

I ended up refactoring my code not to use a list and just produce spans in the first place.

```
void Consume<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> buffer)
// ...

var buffer = new T[512]; 
int itemCount = ProduceListOfItems(buffer); // produce now writes into the buffer

Consume(new ReadOnlySpan<T>(buffer, 0, itemCount);
```

I'm chosing to make the explicit tradeoff of over-allocating the buffer once to avoid making an extra copy later on.

I can do this in my specific case because I know there will a maximum upper bound on the item count, and over-allocating slightly isn't a big deal, however there doesn't appear to be a generalisation here, nor would one ever get added as it would be dangerous.

As always, software performance is the art of making (hopefully favorable) trade-offs.

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own `CustomList<T>` that exposes the underlying array. It is then on user code to use this class correctly.

In particular the `CustomList<T>` will not be aware of any `Span<T>` that you can obtain from the underlying backing array. After taking a `Span<T>` you should not make the list do anything to create a new array or create undefined data in the old array.

The C++ standard library allows user code to obtain direct pointers into `vector<T>` backing storage. They document the conditions under which this is safe. Resizing makes it unsafe for example.

.NET itself does something like this with `MemoryStream`. This class allows you access to the underlying buffer and indeed unsafe operations are possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the example I did in [Unity H4xx](https://github.com/atcarter714/UnityH4xx) with IL + C# and made a plugin for Unity (.NET Framework 4.7.1 to 4.8.x and .NET Standard 2.1) that allows you to use `CollectionMarshal.AsSpan<T>` on a `List<T>` ... it's accomplished by simply breaking visibility / access modifier rules and making the internals of `List<T>` visible to steal the `_items` backing array from it and create a Span. From the Span, you can grab a pointer and literally read/write RAM, but it's *not* recommended to do so unless you know what you're doing.