# How to convert a read only collection to ReadOnlySpan<T>/ReadOnlyMemory<T> without copy by .ToArray()?

Tags: c#

`ReadOnlySpan<T>/ReadOnlyMemory<T>` seems only accepts array `T[]`, but such as `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` are very common, how to convert such read only collection without calling `ToArray()`?

Here is a use case:

```cs
public class Model {
    private readonly byte[]? _data; // the data only need to generate once, 
                                    // and cached for multiple external access by GetData()
    ...
    private byte[] GenerateData() => ...;

    public IReadOnlyList<byte> GetData() => _data ??= GenerateData();
    ...
}
```

```cs
public class NetworkSender {
    ...
    public async Task SendModelData(Model model) {
        ...
        using var client = new UdpClient();
        await client.SendAsync(new ReadOnlyMemory(model.GetData())); // syntax error here..
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: why use a readonly list interface here? why not just return it as a span? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476832/how-can-i-get-a-spant-from-a-listt-while-avoiding-needless-copies

Comment: @DanielA.White Presumably most usages of this method won't want the data as a span, only certain specific ones.

Comment: @Servy yea what I think is happening is the wrong abstraction/interface used here

Comment: In general there is no way to do this because an `IReadOnlyList<T>` might not be implemented using a single contiguous block of memory.  But if your read-only list happens actually to be a `List<T>`, maybe see [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan<T>(List<T>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan).

Comment: @DanielA.White You're right, I don't even know I can return a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` directly. But sometime I can't change the interface which designed by 3rd library.

Answer (score 1):

According to the discussion in this issue:

- https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21727

It appears that exposing `ReadOnlyCollection` as a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` would not be possible because `ReadOnlyCollection` still wraps an `IList` internally, which could have non-contiguous implementations.

From @mgravel:

> Additionally, ReadOnlyCollection wraps a more general IList implementation - impossible to get a span for that, as you don't know that the inner implementation is contiguous, and even if it is: you don't have access to that data, because it is abstracted.

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an interface into a span because an interface can be *anything*, and only certain very specific implementations (anything backed by a contiguously populated array, or something equivalent) can be turned into a span.

If you want the return value of this method to be either a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` or an `IReadOnlyList<T>`, return a type that can be either of those things.

So either return a type with two properties, one of each type (storing a private array to construct either).  Or, since it seems `IReadOnlyList<T>` is the primary use case, return a type that implements that interface but also has a property/method to return a `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

```
public struct ReadOnlyArray<T> : IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private T[] array;
    public ReadOnlyArray(T[] array) { this.array = array; }

    public T this[int index] => array[index];
    public int Count => array.Length;
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => array.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => array.GetEnumerator();

    public ReadOnlySpan<T> Span => new ReadOnlySpan<T>(array);
}
```